# "The" inside or outside quotation marks when naming a thesis

Tags: articles, definite-articles, quotation-marks

When stating the name of a scientific thesis or principle, for example, "the theory of evolution," should "the" be inside or outside the quotation marks?

Put simply, which option is preferable:
(1) "the theory of evolution," or
(2) the "theory of evolution"?

The context for this is that I want to introduce the name of the theory. For example, so-and-so called this theory "..." or this theory is standardly called "...".

Comment: It depends: why are you putting the phrase in quotation marks in the first place?

Comment: Why do you want to put it in quotes? Normally one would simply refer to _the theory of evolution_, without any quotes; the reason/context for why you want to use the quotes may influence the answer about what to do.

Comment: If the title does belong in quotes, why not include any article that's also part of the title? If not, don't.

Comment: The context is that I want to introduce it as a term. For example, so-and-so called this theory "..." or this theory is standardly called the "...".